# Joomla Tag Result Page Accordion

Tags: tags, view, search

I would like to change the Tag Search Result page to list the categories containing the articles found by the Tag Search within an accordion menu.

Explanation: The Categories are the main menu items (without link). All found articles are the submenus (displayed as title) linking to the article in a Modal. Categories without a search result should not be displayed.

I hope everybody understands the idea, anybody has an idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can create a [Template Override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) for the results view.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. You are wright, it has to be done by a template override this I know. The question was more about how it should be coded.

Comment: How it should be coded is a little bit vague. I know exactly what you mean, however the only way to show you would be to basically code it all for you which I doubt anyone will do. My advice would be to stick to Joomla coding standards, within your template override, try to tackle this initially by yourself, and post a question if you run into an actual coding related issue ;)

Comment: This is not a site to ask from others to do your job for free, nor to teach you how to code from scratch. If you have a specific question or problem, we would be glad to help you, but we can't code or customize your website. You would have a better chance if you would hire someone to do this for you, following your requirements.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. I took the advice and hired somebody to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the full answer, BUT someone has already started working on this, though not really a rendering of the search page, more of a menu module, but certainly a very nice start

http://www.demo-joomunited.com/tag-transform

Very nice component, with demo video showing its full workings